# Wordpress: Grid layout - box slider

Tags: css, wordpress, grid, slider, css-grid

Im looking for a slider where slides are boxed and in grid layout.
Something like on those two pages as examples. [link to grid layout slider](https://jannah.tielabs.com/demo/) and [second link to grid layout slider](https://demo.tagdiv.com/newspaper/)

Can anyone help me find such slider? Either free or paid does not matter. Thank you

Comment: what is your question? what do you want to know?

Comment: Can anyone help me find such slider? Either free or paid does not matter. Thank you

Comment: do you want to make a website?

Comment: use kleo theme it have all feature you want 

https://themeforest.net/item/kleo-pro-community-focused-multipurpose-buddypress-theme/6776630

Comment: You can build your own layout like that using the grid system or flex box and incorporate the dynamic content in the template.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find someone who offers a hosting system with wordpress (like altervista), register and they will give you a space to make a website. Then download a theme with your specifications (they explain to you from the site also how to filter according to your needs, it's really easy) and activate it on your site.

[image]